# HP Pavillion 15 ab032tx graphics issue

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, fonts

I just got a new HP laptop a couple of months ago. The problem is that the text looks blurred on all applications dialog boxes, even the Windows default applications like Computer Management, Disk Management. Facing the issue in both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1. Right-click on the Desktop.
2. Select *Screen Resolution*.
3. Select *Make text and other items larger or smaller*.
4. Check the box which says *Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays*.
5. You will be prompted to sign out. Complete this and you should be back to non-blurry text!

Comment: it isn't working for me.